# UIAutomation timeouts usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ui-automation

Guys help me to understand the timeouts usage. The documentation gives quite a couple of words about them:

`popTimeout- Retrieves the previous timeout value from a stack, restores it as the current timeout value, and returns it.`

`pushTimeout - Stores the current timeout value on a stack and sets a new timeout value.`

They also provide some code:

```
target = UIATarget.localTarget();

target.pushTimeout(2);
    // attempt element access
target.popTimeout();
```

But I don't exactly understand how and when to use them. Can anybode give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During automation testing, some elements might not become visible right away. so instruments uses a timeout (default 5 seconds) to wait for requested elements. They call this the grace period.

Sometimes the default grace period might not be what you need, so you can change the timeout to a shorter or longer value.
Using the pushTimeout and popTimeout makes sure that the previous grace period is restored after calling popTimeout, without the need to remember the previous grace period.

For example: in one of my tests, I don't want to wait for a popover to become active, but I just want to know if there is a popover active, and dismiss it if there is:

```
target.pushTimeout(0.0);

if ( target.isDeviceiPad() && ! isNull( popOver= app.mainWindow().popover() ) )
{
    UIALogger.logDebug(" dismiss popup by tapping somewhere");
    popOver.dismiss();
    target.delay(0.2);
}
target.popTimeout();
```

BTW, the isNull() is a custom function I made, but you probably understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I use pushTimeout to set a new timeout and popTimeout to restore previous timeout value?